# nestjs passport serilizethion

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

i am trying to use serilizer from PassportSerializer
but its not being invoke

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
 constructor(private userservice: userService) {
   super();
 }

 serializeUser(user: users, done: Function) {
   console.log('Serializer User');
   done(null, user.id);
 }

 async deserializeUser(payload: any, done: Function) {
   const user = await this.userservice.findone(payload);

   console.log('Deserialize User');
   console.log(user);
   return user ? done(null, user.id) : done(null, null);
 }
}
```

here is my auth module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([users]),
    PassportModule.register({ session: true }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'sdfsdfsdf',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '2h' },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [authControler],
  providers: [
    authService,
    userService,
    SessionSerializer,
    LocalStrategy,
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
})
export class authModule {}
```

and my auth controler

```
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authservice.login(req.user);
  }

  @Post('singup')
  async singup(@Body() user: createUser) {
    return this.authservice.sinup(user);
  }

  @Get('profile')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  getprofile(@Request() req) {
    return this.authservice.login(req.user);
  }
}
```

additionaly as you can see iam using also jwt to genrate token i put the generated object in post man headers but it still gives me unauthorized exception can you tell me why

Comment: Are you just getting a generic 401 with no information?

Comment: with jwt ? i get unauthorized  as i said

Comment: Right, are there any errors in the terminal, or nothing?

Comment: no there is no error

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the super.logIn(request) in the authguard
instead of just calling authguard("local") lile this

```
 AuthGuard('local')
```

this does not call the login() method

this works

```
@Injectable()
export class localAuthGard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const activate = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return activate;
  }
}
```

https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/login/